# Авторизация через API

Tags: android, best-practice

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно делать проверку валидности токена пользователя на мобильном устройстве? Если у меня, к примеру MVP приложение, у которого есть `SplashScreen`, то получается, что в его `SplashScreenPresenter` из `SplashScreenActivity` я должен проверить валидность токена (или его наличие) и если он не валидный (или его нет) то направить его на `SigninActivity` с авторизацией (через `SplashScreenPresenter`), а если все хорошо - то дальше по логике приложения? 
А как быть тогда когда токен стал невалидным когда пользователь уже был с открытым приложением? Или он его открывает через `onResume`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете `Retrofit` (а вернее речь пойдёт о библиотеке `OkHttp` на которой и работает ретрофит) то вы можете воспользоваться `Interceptor`'ами. Они перехватывают все ваши запросы, **ДО** их начала, также  прямо интерсепторе эти запросы можно выполнить и получить ответ, проверив валидность токена (ваш бекенд должен выдать особое сообщение, если токен не валидный). Либо воспользоваться функционалом `CallAdapter`, написав свой кастомный. там вы так же можете обработать результат запроса.

С точки зрения архитектуры - у вас есть `View (Activity)` и её `Presenter`. Этот `Presenter` отвечает только за логику конкретного экрана. Допустим сплеш скрин пытается сделать автологин, для этого нужен заранее готовый токен, который лежит где нибудь в `SharedPreferences`. Так вот, `Presenter` не должен знать где лежит токен, и как конкретно обратиться к серверу. Для этого у вас должен быть специальный класс, назовем его `AuthManager` в котором есть метод `autoLogin()`. И Вот этот менеджер идёт в префы, забирает, токен, логинится.

Если токена нет, то Менеджер сообщает презентеру об ошибке и презентер говорит вьюхе, что надо показать экран авторизации.

Если допустим, токен есть, но он не валидный, то менеджер пытается его рефрешнуть, если получилось то снова автологинится и говорит презентеру что всё окей, презентер запускает в приложение, если рефреш токена не прошел с успехом, то менеджер сообщает презентеру об этом и презентер стартует экран авторизации

Вот примерно такую архитектуру можно использовать. Но это уже как Вам удобнее) Дело вкуса

Если прямо во время использования приложения токен тухнет, то для этого в вашем `Interceptor'e` или `CallAdapter'e` должны быть ссылки на `AuthManager` в виде коллбека. Как только токен тухнет, сразу дёргается `AuthManager` и он уже в экстренном порядке выбрасывает юзера на логин скрин или пытается рефрешнуть токен

Comment: >> "и он уже в экстренном порядке выбрасывает юзера на логин скрин или пытается рефрешнуть токен"

- Я так понял, что `AuthManager` не должен содержать логики рендера? Он кинет исключение, его словить должен `Presenter` и уже `Presenter` должен сказать `View` что нужно отобразить форму авторизации?

Comment: Да, верно. Но в таком случае, каждый ваш презентер должен быть подписан на менеджера, чтобы словить протухший токен. или сделать отдельный класс, который слушает менеджера и занимается только тем, что выбрасываем на логин скрин. Тут идеального решения нет. Каждый делает как считает правильным

Comment: Спасибо большое.